# Questions about the player's attack animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please understand even if my English is not good.

I am currently making an action game. But while I was making it, I ran into a big problem.

The problem is the player's movement.

Usually in a normal action game, when a player attacks, he attacks while moving in the direction of the attack.

And moving while attacking like that is more actionable than staying still and attacking.

So the action game that I'm making also made me move in the direction of attack when the player attacks.

However, the problem here is that the animation that the player attacks and the movement of the player do not match each other, so the movement while attacking is not natural.

This is what happens when you simply insert a moving code while the attack animation is playing.

(I want to show you a moving picture, but I can't upload it here)

The result is that the player slips and attacks as if moving on an icy road.

But of course this is not the result I want.

So the other way to think about it was Root motion.

Root Motion allows you to make very natural movements with just animation.

But the problem is that Root Motion has a fixed area of movement for the player in the first place.

This can cause no problems if there are no obstacles in front of the player.

However, if there is an obstacle in front of the player, the story is different.

when a player attacks, there is an obstacle in front of it (for example, a monster) and if the player's attack hits the monster, it should not move.

However, Root Motion can just pass through the monster because the player's travel distance is fixed.

If so, the solution is to use the animation of Root Motion and move the player in a separate code.

And Unity has this function. It's a method called OnAnimatorMove.

So I tried this method, but the result was also an unnatural player movement.

Eventually, I tried a lot of different ways, but I couldn't find a clean solution, so I'm posting a question here.

Perhaps the reason why this problem appears is that the time and position of the animation move do not match with the way I move it to the code.

So finally, the key point of this article is if you know how to implement an attack with a natural movement when a character attacks.

Thank you so much for reading this long article, and if anyone knows how to solve this elaborate problem, please let me know.

It is the same as above.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is a _question and answer_ (Q&A) site **not** a wiki or diary site.  Consider breaking your post into a question and posting your answer below.  This way you will gain reputation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it reads like a diary/wiki article.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will try to not use root motion and instead use MoveTowards to move your character in the attack sequence. I mean, when attack start calculate a position where he could end, lets say its 1 meter away from initial position, then with disabled root motion, user MoveTowards to just move the transform of the character at some pace towards the target position you have calculated before. If there is obstacle or wall you have to use this information when setting the initial target position (use raycast to check if there is wall or monster ahead in 1 meter of distance) so if the wall is 1 meter away then set the target destination to 0.5 meters away from player and move it towards that position and so on. I hope this solves your trouble